# Pythons getattr in Ruby

Tags: python, ruby

In python, it has getattr for example I could do:

```
 class test:
       def say(word):
           return word
```

Doing,

```
getattr(test,'say')('something')
```

returns this:

```
'something'
```

Because you filled it the def say with "something" with getattr.

I have tried some methods in ruby, but the only way I can get it to work is actually doing self.say('something') within the class is there something like getattr for ruby? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ruby:

```
class Test
  def say(word)
    word
  end
end

test = Test.new
test.send(:say, "something")  #=> "something"
```

Comment: `test.send("say", "something")` also works, I learned a few days ago.

Comment: @steenslag Ah, I see. I will give that a try as well.